# fasta file: replace header with filename

Tags: bash, sed, fasta

I want to replace all the headers (starting with `>`) with `>{filename}`, of all `*.fasta` files inside my `directory` AND concatenate them afterwards

content of my `directory`

```
speciesA.fasta
speciesB.fasta
speciesC.fasta
```

example of file, `speciesA.fasta`

```
>protein1 description
MJSUNDKFJSKFJSKFJ
>protein2 anothername
KEFJKSDJFKSDJFKSJFLSJDFLKSJF
>protein3 somewordshere
KSDAFJLASDJFKLAJFL
```

my desired output (only for `speciesA.fasta` now):

```
>speciesA
MJSUNDKFJSKFJSKFJ
>speciesA
KEFJKSDJFKSDJFKSJFLSJDFLKSJF
>speciesA
KSDAFJLASDJFKLAJFL
```

This is my code:

```
for file in *.fasta; do var=$(basename $file .fasta) | sed 's/>.*/>$var/' $var.fasta >>$var.outfile.fasta; done
```

but all I get is

```
>$var
MJSUNDKFJSKFJSKFJ
>$var
KEFJKSDJFKSDJFKSJFLSJDFLKSJF

[and so on ...]
```

Where did i make a mistake??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bash loop is superfluous.  Try:

```
awk '/^>/{print ">" substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-6); next} 1' *.fasta
```

This approach is safe even if the file names contain special or regex-active characters.

#### How it works

- `/^>/ {print ">" substr(FILENAME, 1, length(FILENAME)-6); next}`

  For any line that begins `>`, the commands in curly braces are executed.  The first command prints `>` followed by all but the last 6 letters of the filename.  The second command, `next`, skips the rest of the commands on the line and jumps to start over with the `next` line.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Example

Let's consider a directory with two (identical) test files:

```
$ cat speciesA.fasta
>protein1 description
MJSUNDKFJSKFJSKFJ
>protein2 anothername
KEFJKSDJFKSDJFKSJFLSJDFLKSJF
>protein3 somewordshere
KSDAFJLASDJFKLAJFL
$ cat speciesB.fasta
>protein1 description
MJSUNDKFJSKFJSKFJ
>protein2 anothername
KEFJKSDJFKSDJFKSJFLSJDFLKSJF
>protein3 somewordshere
KSDAFJLASDJFKLAJFL
```

The output of our command is:

```
$ awk '/^>/{print ">" substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-6); next} 1' *.fasta
>speciesA
MJSUNDKFJSKFJSKFJ
>speciesA
KEFJKSDJFKSDJFKSJFLSJDFLKSJF
>speciesA
KSDAFJLASDJFKLAJFL
>speciesB
MJSUNDKFJSKFJSKFJ
>speciesB
KEFJKSDJFKSDJFKSJFLSJDFLKSJF
>speciesB
KSDAFJLASDJFKLAJFL
```

The output has the substitutions and concatenates all the input files.

Answer (score 2):

In `sed` you need to use double quotes for variable expansion. Otherwise, they will be considered as literal text.

```
for file in *.fasta;
   do
       sed -i "s/>.*/${file%%.*}/" "$file" ;
done
```

Comment: for some reason I had to modify this to work in zsh and retain the ">"
`for file in *.fasta;                                                              
   do
       tag=">"${file%%.*}
       sed -i "s/>.*/$tag/" "$file"  ;
done`